# Creating a playlist does not require scope=playlist-modify-private

Tags: spotify

I inadvertently set scope=user-read-private for my application and found out that it is still possible to create playlists and add tracks to them. I would have expected a 'not authorised' response.

There are 2 scopes which I would have expected to control this access 
playlist-modify-public
playlist-modify-private

They do not appear to be redundant.

Has anyone else able to confirm this behaviour?

Edit: It appears that the scope that you request for the application is only checked to be a part of the existing total scope already requested for the application. If you reduce the requested scope it does not reduce the total scope and thus pre-exiting parts are still present.

Comment: I can not confirm the behaviour by trying with developer console on https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/post-playlists/ and setting only scope=user-read-private. I get 403 "Insufficient client scope". This feels more like an issue to bring up in https://github.com/spotify/web-api than here.

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to have the `playlist-modify-public` scope, you just can't create *private* playlists. Read more about the [public, private and collaborative model](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/working-with-playlists/#public-private-and-collaborative-status) on our Developer site.

Comment: I have read and understand this model. What I am saying above is that I can create a private or public playlist and add tracks to it via an application with just scope = user-read-private.

Comment: Interesting, that sounds like a bug to me. Could you please file it in the Github repository - https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/new?

Comment: Further investigation shows that I was incorrect. When the refresh token is used it reveals that the application already has the necessary scope parts.

I am only asking for the read only part but it appears this does not reduce the scopes already present from prior requests.

This question can be considered answered now.

Comment: Thanks Mark! Feel free to set my answer as the correct one (to give me Internet points, but also to show that it's answered.). Also, I think it'd be great if you edited your own question to show what actually happened in case someone has a similar issue. Thanks!